# Drag and Drop using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to do a simple drag-drop using jQuery. I have not done anything so far, but previous attempts were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)? Simple use case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#draggable").draggable();
    });
</script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Online Demo Created.](http://jsbin.com/exojo3/)**

**[See this please.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/05/implement-drag-and-drop-example-jquery-javascript-html.html)**

**Other Option:**

**[JQuery Drag & Drop Plugin.](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/45)**

Comment: @Safraz I didn't see a drop example on that page. It had a `droppable` call in code snippet, but then did not have a drop target in the "Full   Code". Did I miss something?