# JavaScript (jQuery) Drag And Drop Support

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Are there any libraries that add in support for standard drag and drop functionality that is built with either jQuery or just plain JavaScript?  I would perfer something other than jQuery UI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621289/drag-and-drop-using-jquery)

Comment: not for anything but using google or searching this site I find to be a first step in finding what I'm looking for rather than asking the same question again

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is going with [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). But there are other options like [script.aculo.us](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/draggable/)

Answer (score 0):

http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag is a great dragging jquery plugin if your looking for an alternative to jquery ui